# Why are both 選び and 祝福した taking the same object even though one is in their masu stem and the other isn't?

Tags: grammar, renyōkei

I noticed that in this sentence:

> 主{しゅ}はあなたを選{えら}**び**、祝福{しゅくふく}した。

選{えら}び (masu stem) and 祝福{しゅくふく}した (noun + suru verb) take the same object. Is there a grammar rule for this? I can't seem to find any on the net. If I take one object with two verbs, do I have to write them in their masu stem?

Can't I just say:

> 主{しゅ}はあなたを選{えら}**んで**祝福{しゅくふく}した。

Comment: Please include the entire sentence. That is not a complete sentence. You may not have noticed that it went on to the next line or page.

Comment: I gave the full sentence @naruto san.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 主{しゅ}はあなたを選{えら}んで祝福{しゅくふく}した。

This is colloquial.

> 主{しゅ}はあなたを選{えら}び、祝福{しゅくふく}した。

This is literary.

選び is in this form because it precedes another verb/verbal phrase in one sentence. It is called 中止法 or 連用中止.
See [連用中止形](https://www.imabi.net/renyouchuushikei.htm).