# Is there any other difference between なくなり vs なくなって besides the former being more formal than the latter?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I can't figure out if the difference between the two is just a matter of formality or if there are cases I would prefer to use one over the other **regarding the context or nuance I want to convey**.
For example, what is the difference between:

日本語の練習が続かなくなり、だんだん勉強を止めてしまいました

and:

日本語の練習が続かなくなって、だんだん勉強を止めてしまいました

Thank you

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between 選び and 選んで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100593/32952)? (specially the [referred article](https://www.imabi.net/renyouchuushikei.htm) in the linked post)

Comment: I fixed the grammar problem unrelated to your main concern. 続く is an intransitive verb that does not take an object, but your sentence had two を-marked objects.

Comment: Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a simple case like this, the only difference is that the masu-stem sounds more formal.

In a more complex sentences, te-forms and masu-stems can coexist. In such cases, I think te-forms tend to be used to describe a sequence of events, whereas masu-stems tend to be used to list things in parallel.

In this example, both sentences are correct, but Sentence 1 feels more natural and sophisticated than Sentence 2:

1. 佐藤さんは高校を卒業して調理師になり、田中さんは免許を取って教師になりました。
2. 佐藤さんは高校を卒業し調理師になって、田中さんは免許を取り教師になりました。

(This may be obvious to you, but note that masu-stem and te-form are basically different concepts, and they are usually not interchangeable in most other cases. For example, subsidiary verbs only follow a te-form.)

Comment: Thank you for the detaild explanation!